# ElasticBeanstalk Docker host network mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is there a way to launch Docker containers in a host networking mode in EB environments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, as far as I know.

Support for host networking mode was introduced in ECS in August 2016 (see issue https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/185), but it looks like it's still missing in EB environments (at least for MultiDocker envs). I've tried it half a year a go and now again, it's still not working (with attribute "networkMode", same configuration like in ECS).

Same question was asked in the AWS forums https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=741854&#741854 and the answer was also a "No".